# anonymous audit log access to specific pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, auditing, log

How can I restrict access to a SharePoint or Teams file’s history, while allowing anyone in my company to access the content? Essentially we want anyone to be able to access a couple of pages of data but want strict controls on anyone being able to identify who accessed these pages. Or, is there some way I can make all access anonymous access to specific pages, or do I need to build an anonymous SharePoint site.

Answer (score 0):

Which version do you use? SharePoint Online or SharePoint server?

If the former,we can not enable anyone link(anonymous access) for SharePoint modern page.

> The Anyone with the link option might be greyed out if you attempt to
> share .aspx pages. Sharing .aspx pages is not supported.

If the later, please refer below article to enable anonymous access for pages library:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/05/how-to-enable-anonymous-access-in-sharepoint-2013.html

Also, anonymous users do not have permission to view anonymous access audit reports.

Comment: Do you have any progress on this issue?

Please remember to update this thread if you need further assistance.